# How to use mixin for grid layout with zurb foundation?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I am testing Foundation but I don't find any documentation about using sass to make my css with my custom classes/IDs.
I get only the basic markup but nothing like:

```
@include column();
@extend seven;
```

Thanks for help.

EDIT:
my folder structure :

- my-theme > sass > layout-home.scss + base.scss
- my-theme > zurb > foundation.scss
- my-theme > zurb > components > All the scss files of ZF
- in layout-home.scss : `@import "base.scss";`
- in _base.scss : `@import "../zurb/foundation";`
- in foundation.scss : import of all components

no compass error detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is plenty of documentation in the official Foundation site, for example, for info about how to implement the grid: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

You will see at the bottom of each section there is the explanation for using scss with Foundation and all the variables and mixins. For example, you can use the mixin `@include grid-column(options)` to include number of columns in a tag with any class/ID you like.

Comment: ok figure out my non load css : wrong name into the info file of my theme...dumb error

Comment: how can i enlarge the width of a row ?

Comment: As this is a different question from the original, I would suggest that you write a new post for it. Also, if you find my answer to your question above helpful, maybe you could vote it so others can see it.